# Setting Control Template of WPF ColorPicker

Tags: wpf, exception, controltemplate, color-picker, object-reference

I am Trying to Set the Control Template of the WPF colorpicker to rectangle. I want that only a rectangular shape is displayed in place of ColorPicker ComboBox. But When I place any control in ControlTemplate, I get the error that "Object reference not set to instance of an object".

This is my wpf code:

```
<wpfx:ColorPicker Name="ColorPicker1" Height="30" DisplayColorAndName="False"
                  Margin="29,72,366,209"
                  SelectedColorChanged="ColorPicker1_SelectedColorChanged">
    <wpfx:ColorPicker.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Rectangle ></Rectangle>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </wpfx:ColorPicker.Template>
</wpfx:ColorPicker>
```

Any suggestions of what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Am presuming you are using: http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/  .... Did you miss out the closing tag ? </wpfx:ColorPicker>

Comment: No .. .Sorry I copy pasted .. so in actual code its not missed.

Comment: Could you please post the stack trace of the exception you get?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most probable reason is that ColorPicker control expects some element within its Template, usually such elements has special name which starts from "PART_...". I think in order to get more information about which element is missed you have to look into the default color picker template and find out which elements there and which names they have.

Probable fix scenario: find the name of the control which is mandatory for ColorPicker control and give this name to your rectangle.

Here is the ColorPicker default template:

```
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ColorPicker}">
           <Grid>
              <ToggleButton x:Name="PART_ColorPickerToggleButton"
                            IsTabStop="True"
                            MinHeight="22" 
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
                            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                            IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                            IsHitTestVisible="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource InverseBoolConverter}}"
                            Style="{TemplateBinding ButtonStyle}">
                 <Grid Margin="2">
                    <Border x:Name="ColorOnly" Style="{StaticResource ColorDisplayStyle}" />

                    <Border x:Name="ColorAndName" Background="White" Visibility="Hidden">
                       <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                          <Border HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="20" Margin="2,1,4,1" Style="{StaticResource ColorDisplayStyle}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FFC9CACA" />
                          <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedColorText, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                       </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                 </Grid>
              </ToggleButton>

              <Popup x:Name="PART_ColorPickerPalettePopup" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=PART_ColorPickerToggleButton, Path=IsChecked}" StaysOpen="False" AllowsTransparency="True" Focusable="False" HorizontalOffset="1" VerticalOffset="1" PopupAnimation="Slide">
                 <Border BorderThickness="1" Background="{StaticResource PopupBackgroundBrush}" BorderBrush="{StaticResource ColorPickerDarkBorderBrush}" Padding="3">
                    <Grid>
                       <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                          <RowDefinition />
                          <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                       </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                       <Grid x:Name="_gridStandardColorsHost" Margin="4">
                          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                             <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                          </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                          <!-- Available Colors -->
                          <Grid Grid.Row="1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ShowAvailableColors, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                             <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                   <RowDefinition />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding AvailableColorsHeader}" Background="AliceBlue" Padding="2" Margin="0,0,0,1" />
                                <ListBox x:Name="PART_AvailableColors"
                                         Grid.Row="1"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableColors, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                         Style="{StaticResource ColorListStyle}" />
                             </Grid>
                          </Grid>

                          <!-- Standard Colors-->
                          <Grid Grid.Row="2" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ShowStandardColors, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                             <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding StandardColorsHeader}" Background="AliceBlue" Padding="2" Margin="0,1,0,1" />
                                <ListBox x:Name="PART_StandardColors"
                                         Grid.Row="1"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding StandardColors, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"                                                      
                                         Style="{StaticResource ColorListStyle}" />
                             </Grid>
                          </Grid>

                          <!-- Recent Colors-->
                          <Grid Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,1,0,1" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ShowRecentColors, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}">
                             <Grid>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                   <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding RecentColorsHeader}" Background="AliceBlue" Padding="2" Margin="0,1,0,1" />
                                <ListBox x:Name="PART_RecentColors"
                                         Grid.Row="1"
                                         ItemsSource="{Binding RecentColors, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                         Style="{StaticResource ColorListStyle}" />
                             </Grid>
                          </Grid>
                       </Grid>

                       <!-- ColorCanvas -->
                       <Grid x:Name="_colorCanvasHost" Visibility="Collapsed">
                          <local:ColorCanvas x:Name="PART_ColorCanvas"
                                             Background="Transparent"
                                             BorderThickness="0"
                                             SelectedColor="{Binding SelectedColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                       </Grid>

                       <Separator Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,5,0" />

                       <!-- More Colors Button -->
                       <ToggleButton x:Name="_colorMode" Grid.Row="2" Content="Advanced" Margin="5" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ShowAdvancedButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                    </Grid>
                 </Border>
              </Popup>
           </Grid>
           <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
              <Trigger Property="DisplayColorAndName" Value="True">
                 <Setter TargetName="ColorOnly" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                 <Setter TargetName="ColorAndName" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
              </Trigger>
              <Trigger SourceName="_colorMode" Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
                 <Setter TargetName="_colorMode" Property="Content" Value="Standard" />
                 <Setter TargetName="_colorCanvasHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                 <Setter TargetName="_gridStandardColorsHost" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
              </Trigger>
           </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
```